# Is it possible to have 2 ASP.NET Core sites in one Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to have 2 ASP.NET Core Web API apps inside the one App Service?

I understand that it would be better to have the 2 sites in separate App Services, but our use case is a bit unique.

We're trying to add the 2nd site for the purposes of using the applicationInitialization feature to introduce a delay between our app starting and the instance being given to the App Service load balancer.
I could go into a lot more detail on this, but what I desire for now is to bolt-on an additional web site that the applicationInitialization can call to delay the startup process.

I've tried:

```
Folder structure: 
  /mySite
  /mySite2
  web.config

Folder structure: 
  /mySite2
  mySite.dll
  web.config
```

With respective web.Configs looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="mySite" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mysite\mySite.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="mySite2" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mySite2\mySite2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mySite.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="mySite2" inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\mySite2\mySite2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES. It is possible, you can have two applications on a single web app with a [`virtual directory.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory)

From docs:

> Virtual Directories are supported for Azure Websites. See Configuring
>   Azure Websites for what you can do through the Azure Management
>   Portal. From the Azure Portal, click on the Website and go to
>   Configure, then scroll down to virtual applications and directories
>   (the last config section). Just enter your virtual directory and the
>   physical path relative to the site root and click Save.

Comment: I actually had everything setup correctly, however the App Service had fell into a bad state during my "testing". Deleting and re-starting cured days worth of attempts...